# Docker Laradock Browsertest with Dusk: default test returned empty page

Tags: php, docker, laravel-dusk, laradock

- Docker: 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
- Laravel 6.*

I try to move my projects from Vbox to DOCKER. Currently it is a LARAVEL-Project. For this purpose I installed a test project following the [instruction by laradock](https://laradock.io/guides/#running-laravel-dusk-tests).

Seems working fine, but if I try to execute the default browser test, the response from the test is an empty page...

.en.dusk

```
...
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
...
```

tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{

    /**
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--no-sandbox',
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://localhost:9515',
            DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options)
        );
    }

    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/');

            var_dump(
                $browser->driver->getCurrentURL(),
                $browser->driver->getPageSource()
            );
        });
    }
}
```

...and running the test:

```
root@339f233de952:/var/www/project_http# php artisan dusk
PHPUnit 8.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

R                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)string(22) "http://localhost:8000/"
string(39) "<html><head></head><body></body></html>"


Time: 1.38 seconds, Memory: 16.00 MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
This test did not perform any assertions

/var/www/project_http/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:37

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Risky: 1.
```

Seems the issue is about the *APP_URL* in the *.env.dusk* file, **but which url do I have to use, to run the test successfully**?

If I call the page from the host, the page shows content like expected (the default page by laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally i've found the solution...

I have an multiple project and so i configured it like the [instruction for multiple projects](https://laradock.io/getting-started/#b-setup-for-multiple-projects) by Laradock.

Unfortunally the manual does not explain (at least i dont have found it), what to set inside the services to access the specific application with specific url.

I have 2 application like this:

- project1
- project2

I have 2 conf-files inside the sites folder of nginx.

*project1.conf*

```
server {
    ...

    server_name project1.local;
    ...
```

*project2.conf*

```
server {
    ...

    server_name project2.local;
```

To make it work, i had to set additionally lines inside the *docker-compose.yml* at service *workspace* at section *extra_hosts*:

```
...
### Workspace Utilities ##################################
    workspace:
      ...
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
        - "project1.local:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
        - "project2.local:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      ....
...
```

Now the test work's fine :-))